# How to change user name in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My user was migrated to another domain. I registered a wrong user name and I want to edit it again. I can only change my email but not the user name. I cannot find a way to register again.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your organization name. You can do this from the "Organization Settings" (which is at the bottom in the left panel at the time of this writing).